# Convert json array to a csv using postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

Using postgres version 14.x, how do I convert the contents of a column (TEXT type) containing a json array to a csv?

For example

mytable
mycolumn
["10.0.0.1/32", "10.0.0.2/32", "10.0.0.3/32"]

to
10.0.0.1/32,10.0.0.3/32,10.0.0.3/32

Thanks!

Comment: `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(mycolumn,'"',''),'['.''),']','')`, but what have you tried yourself ?

Comment: What do you want to use the comma-separate value for? Do you actually want to download a CSV file?

Comment: Probably you meant putting those as a new column? If so then: select id, x
from 
    mytable t
    cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(t.mycolumn::jsonb) x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) to carry out this task.

The matching pattern (`[\[\]"]`) should be a collection of characters to be replaced, namely the open bracket, the closed bracket and the double quote, to be escaped (`\`) and enclosed in brackets.

In order to make sure the operation replaces all occurrences of brackets and double quotes, you need to specify `'g'` flag as fourth argument of the function

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '[\[\]"]', '', 'g');
```

**Output**:

| mycolumn |
| --- |
| 10.0.0.1/32, 10.0.0.2/32, 10.0.0.3/32 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qQcbkcY4rhu7SFfTrPa8zG/0).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`jsonb_array_elements_text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html) to Expands a JSON array to a set of text values then `string_agg` to concatenate those values :

```
select id, string_agg(elem, ',')
from 
    mytable t
    cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(t.mycolumn::jsonb) elem
group by id
```

Simple data :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id int,
  mycolumn  varchar(250)
);


insert into mytable values
(1, '["10.0.0.1/32", "10.0.0.2/32", "10.0.0.3/32"]'),
(2, '["10.0.2.1/32", "10.0.2.2/32", "10.0.2.3/32"]');
```

Result :

```
id  csv_line
1   10.0.0.1/32,10.0.0.2/32,10.0.0.3/32
2   10.0.2.1/32,10.0.2.2/32,10.0.2.3/32
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/INXab6R6)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, using my data, this returned a single row with a column containing all the values. I must have missed something, as obviously the demo code works just fine.  Will try again with other data.